# Is there any name for a rule like $\neg P \therefore \neg (P\wedge Q)?$

Tags: logic

Learning logic for the first time, I came to the conclusion that this statement I stumbled on is true.

$\neg p$

$\therefore \neg(p\wedge q)$

Is there a formal name for this rule?

Comment: Using DeMorgan's laws, you can rewrite $\neg(p \wedge q)$ as $\neg p \vee \neg q$.

Comment: And building upon @SimonFraser's comment, this rule is incidentally called "Disjunctive Amplification" or "Disjunctive Introduction". One of my profs called it "If you can say less, then you can say more."

Comment: I'd describe it as an instance of _argumentum a fortiori_, but that's not an official name.

Comment: To expand on an earlier comment: $\neg p$ implies $\neg p \lor \neg q$ by the disjunction introduction rule. By DeMorgan's law, $\neg p \lor \neg q \equiv \neg (p \wedge q)$.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out in the comments, it is closely related to

$P$

$\therefore P \lor Q$

which goes by the name of Disjunctive Introduction or Addition (and, apparently, Disjunctive Amplification).

However, since you are not actually adding a disjunct when going from $\neg P$ to $\neg (P \land Q)$, maybe we can regard it as an instance of the more general principle of 'Weakening', which is simply any case where you make you weaken your statement.

Also, in the system of Existential Graphs this would be an elementary instance of Insertion.